# postgresql - copy from file to a table command with Base 64 encoding option

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a requirement to load the data from a file to PostgreSQL table using Python script. But the file is holding Hexadecimal characters in one of the column. I am trying to encode the data before loading to the table but I couldn't able.

Here is my copy command

file_name = "abc.txt"

sql = "COPY tep_data.batch_load FROM STDIN DELIMITER '~' CSV HEADER BASE64"
cursor.copy_expert(sql, open(file_name, "r"))

LINE 1: ...p_data.batch_load FROM STDIN DELIMITER '~' CSV HEADER BASE64
^
Appreciate your help

Comment: There's no reason to encode hexadecimal characters.  Do you actually mean you have non-printable characters?

Comment: Hi Tim...yes I have Hex decimal characters in one of the column and I dont want to corrupt the data. Downstream systems gonna read and process it. When I try insert the data to the table without encoding, I am getting the below error.

"psycopg2.errors.QueryCanceled: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call: UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3548: invalid start byte
CONTEXT:  COPY batch_load, line 1"

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're saying.  Having hexadecimal characters just means you have a string like `"001122334455"`.  That's just a string.  That doesn't need any special handling at all.  Now, if you have binary data (like the Python string "\xAA\xBB\xCC", then that does need special handling.  Perhaps you should post a hex dump of a few lines of your input.

Comment: The error you're getting suggests the string parts of your file are not UTF-8.  Are you running Windows?  Perhaps you should try `...open(file_name, "r", encoding="cp1252"))`.